# Getting Error Cannot read property 'value' of undefined while passing value in parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, frontend

All i want is to simply pass this array as a parameter from Book.js and receive this on Cart.js the other component, but i keep getting this error in Cart.js : TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined.

App.js

```
<Route path='/Cart/:value' render={()=>(
           <div><Header/>
           <Cart/>
           </div>
          )}     
        />
```

Header.js

```
 <div className="header">
                    <Link to ="/">Home</Link>
                    <Link to ="/Books">Books</Link>
                    <Link to="/Cart/value">Cart</Link>
  </div>
```

Book.js

```
  { all_books.map((one_book, index) =>
                <div key={index} className="single_book">
                        {/* {Object.values(one_book).map((a_book, index) =>
                        <h4>{a_book}</h4>
                        )}   */}
                    <h3>Book Name :- {one_book[1]}</h3>
                    <h3>Price :- {one_book[2]}</h3>
                    <h3>Author :- {one_book[3]}</h3>
                    <h3>No. of Pages :- {one_book[4]}</h3>


                        <Link  
                        to = {`/Cart/${one_book}`}>

                        Add to Cart

                        </Link>
                    </center>
                </div>
            )}
```

Cart.js

```
  <div>
             {this.props.params.value}
            </div>
```

Comment: Are you planning to pass a whole object using url param??

Comment: @Sifat Yess Thats the plan

Comment: i don't think that's any good idea, you can either pass the book ID using url or create a context to maintain all the books

Comment: I tried passing book id, it still shows same error

Answer (score 1):

You can try passing the props in your render like this.

```
<Route path='/Cart/:id' render={(props)=>(
       <div><Header/>
       <Cart id={props.match.params.id} />
       </div>
      )}     
    />
```

Also make sure you are passing the proper ID.